# WebSocket connection from Dart/Flutter to Google Cloud Run fails

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, dart-io

did anyone use WebSocket connections between a *Flutter/Dart client* and a server running on *Google Cloud Run* successfully?

Exactly this combination fails for me.

The client works with the same server on localhost. 
Another client works with the same server on Cloud Run.

I tried to find the cause of the problem, so I have created a complete bug reproducer with clients in Dart and Python and servers in Java and Python:

- **Dart client** (the README contains the outputs of the messages sent and received and the aborted connection): 
  https://github.com/buehren/websocket-client-dart
- **Java/Quarkus WebSocket Echo Server** (including a "Run in Google Cloud" button): 
  https://github.com/buehren/websocket-echo-server-quarkus
- **Python WebSocket Echo Server** (including a "Run in Google Cloud" button): 
  https://github.com/buehren/websocket-echo-server-python

The Dart client works with WebSocket echo server running on localhost:

```
> dart run wsclient.dart --url ws://localhost:8080/websocket

2021-02-26 21:25:22.293451 Starting connection attempt to ws://localhost:8080/websocket ...
2021-02-26 21:25:22.418794 WebSocket readyState: 1
2021-02-26 21:25:23.446877 Sending 'hello'
2021-02-26 21:25:23.458083 Received data: echo of hello
2021-02-26 21:25:24.422013 Sending 'how are you?'
2021-02-26 21:25:24.422752 Received data: echo of how are you
2021-02-26 21:25:26.433450 Sending 'still there?'
2021-02-26 21:25:26.436280 Received data: echo of still there?
^C
^C
```

The Dart client does NOT work with WebSocket echo server running on Google Cloud Run — the WebSocket is closed right after the Dart client sends data:

```
> dart run wsclient.dart --url wss://websocket-echo-server-quarkus-xxxxxxxxxx-xx.x.run.app/websocket

2021-02-26 21:25:40.539316 Starting connection attempt to wss://websocket-echo-server-quarkus-xxxxxxxxxx-xx.x.run.app/websocket ...
2021-02-26 21:25:40.844298 WebSocket readyState: 1
2021-02-26 21:25:41.851590 Sending 'hello'
2021-02-26 21:25:41.898587 CONNECTION DONE!
readyState=3
closeCode=1005
closeReason=

2021-02-26 21:25:42.847345 Sending 'how are you?'
2021-02-26 21:25:44.848959 Sending 'still there?'
```

Do you have any idea how this can happen? Did I do anything wrong in my code?

Thank you very much

Thomas

Comment: Start by creating an example that shows the problem and the errors. Your question has not details that can help solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @JohnHanley: Did you see the links to my three GitHub repositories containing detailed reproducible examples?

Comment: Your question must be self contained and not require going to off-site resources. Links break, are deleted, etc. possibly rendering your question useless in the future. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask